# KrakenJS and firebase async not returning value

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, kraken.js

I'm using the KrakenJS node framework for my project and using Firebase as the data storage. What I'm trying to achieve is once a user has logged in it will retrieve data (JSON) and pass it to the dust template so I can loop through and render the data on the page.

But as Firebase is Async it seems I'm returning an empty JSON before any of the data from Firebase is gathered and put into the JSON object to be sent to the dustjs templates.

example of my code:

```
var userBoards = {},
        getBoardDetails = function(boardList) {
        for (var key in boardList) {
            if (boardList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    request(firebasePath+'/boards/'+key+'.json?auth='+token, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        userBoards[key] = JSON.parse(body);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return userBoards; // Once populated return back JSON object
        },
        getBoardList = function(uid, token) {
            request(firebasePath+'/user-boards/'+uid+'.json?auth='+token, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    return getBoardDetails(JSON.parse(body)); // Show the HTML for the Modulus homepage.
                }
            });
        };
```

My question is, how do I return either:

- each individual value to my template so they render individually
- return the entire JSON of userBoards back to my template so I can loop through the values.

Comment: You seem to know why you can't return the value: it hasn't loaded yet. What is your question?

Comment: Whoops, seems I missed off the actual question. Update the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out: you cannot return something now that is still being loaded.

In many other programming environment you can make the program wait for the data to be loaded, but most JavaScript environments are not of that kind.

It often helps (for me at least) to reframe/rephrase the problem. Instead of "I want to load this data and then render it with a template", think of it as "whenever this data has loaded, I will render it with this template". Not only will this work asynchronously, as an added bonus it will also work if the data changes and Firebase synchronizes the new value to your app.

To implement them words, you typically invert the flow from:

```
var boards = getBoardList(uid, token);
renderBoards(boards);
```

Into:

```
monitorBoardsAnd(uid, token, renderBoards);
```

In that last line, we're passing the follow-up action (`renderBoards()`) into the asynchronous action (`monitorBoardsAnd()`). Here's how you could implement the latter:

```
    monitorBoardsAnd = function(uid, token, callback) {
        request(firebasePath+'/user-boards/'+uid+'.json?auth='+token, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                callback(JSON.parse(body)); // Show the HTML for the Modulus homepage.
            }
        });
    };
```

In this fragment I've removed the logic for loading each individual board. If you need this, you can keep a counter and pass another callback into `getBoardDetails()` to increase that counter until you've read all of them. I would not recommend this however; since you're firing a REST request for each board, the performance will be pretty bad.

If you're showing a list of boards for each user, consider including the details that you display in the list of each user. You'll be duplicating data, but it'll prevent the need for an expensive join.

Comment: Thanks for that Frank. The main reasons for having separated out the boards was 1. The boards can be shared with other users so placing in their own user details I don't believe would work due to security. 2. I thought having all board details in the user details could be a performance issue as I would be returning all that unnecessary info when I just want the user info and no board info.
Am I doing this wrong?